# Excel: Using vlookup to return value between 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that looks like this:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+----+--------+
| A  |       B       |        C        | D  |   E    |
+----+---------------+-----------------+----+--------+
| ID | Primary Email | Secondary Email | ID | Emails |
| -  | -             | -               | -  | -      |
| -  | -             | -               | -  | -      |
+----+---------------+-----------------+----+--------+
```

I need a formula/macro that compares the E column (emails) with column B and C and return them in column F.

I'm trying to use `VLOOKUP` but it can only takes 1 index. Is there an alternative?

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$C$10000,3,FALSE)
```

This formula only returns from column C but I need it to return from both

Comment: Please add some example data with your expected result ;).

Answer (score 1):

You could add two Vlookups together, `=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$C$10000,2,FALSE)&", "&VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$C$10000,3,FALSE)`.